# CS0426 error thrown in switch block, but not within an if statement, how to fix?

Tags: c#, .net-core, switch-statement, .net-core-3.1

I've got this enum:

```
namespace MyApp.Internal.Enums
{
    public enum EServerType
    {
        API
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the Factory pattern to get a class according to a string, and this is my factory (with both the working code and the error):

```
using MyApp.Handlers.Interfaces;
using MyApp.Internal.Enums;
using MyApp.Services.Interfaces;

namespace MyApp.Handlers
{
    public class ServerCallerFactory : IServerCallerFactory
    {
        public IServerCaller GetServerCaller(string serverType)
        {
            if (serverType.ToUpper() == EServerType.API.ToString())
            {

            }

            switch (serverType.ToUpper())
            {
                case EServerType.API.ToString():
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I prefer switching over the string instead of using multiple if statements of course.
The `if` block isn't throwing any compiler error, however, the `switch` block is!

Error thrown by compiler: `CS0426 The type name 'API' does not exist in the type EServerType`.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I think, there are two same name EServerType enum declared in different namespace of your project, is it right ? If it is right, you must use full name of enum. For example: MyApp.Internal.Enums.EServerType.API.ToString() ...

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? Aside: `string.Equals(..., StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` is more efficient than `ToUpper`

Comment: @RamilAliyev I've already checked that and there's no duplicate enums. Also, that doesn't explain why the `if` doesn't throw a compiler error but the `switch` does.

Comment: @Charlieface I want to use the `switch` block, the `if` is there just to show that it doesn't throw the error.. Which for my little experience is weird. If I am not mistaken, my C# version should be C# 8.0

Comment: It's a nonconstant expression, so you need to use pattern-matching to do this `case var s when (s == EServerType.API.ToString())` Why don't you just use `Enum.TryParse` it has a case-insensitive version

Comment: The code you posted is illegal. You can't call `ToString()` in an enum's `case` statement like that. Per the previous comment, you could change to the more dynamic pattern-matching syntax, but since what you really want to do is identify the enum value that corresponds to the string being given, you just need to parse the enum. See duplicate.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you.. I've actually used the Enum.TryParse in another piece of code, but it wasn't switch statement. I didn't think of using it here.. I'll go with that probably.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I guess working with VB.net  for the past few years made me think that I can do that in C#... Thank you.. I will go with the TryParse and switch over the Enum type itself.

Comment: You can use NameOf, because value of ToString is not known at compile time and case should be a constant value

Comment: @PaulKaram case requires const value, ToString() is working runtime in your code. Therefore you can use nameof expression, that nameof is working compile time. Change your code like as below, it will working: `switch (serverType.ToUpper()){
                case nameof(EServerType.API):
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }`